# BASH function with tmux send-keys

Tags: bash, tmux

I'm having problems putting "send-keys" into a bash function. Here's a minimal example:

```
function keys {
  tmux send-keys -t work:1 $*
}

tmux new-session -d -s work
keys "pwd" c-m "ls -latr" c-m
tmux attach-session -t work
```

The keys argument here is exactly what I'd type on the command-line as an argument to `tmux send-keys`. It almost works, but strips spaces, so I see `ls-latr` all as one word. But if I put quotes around the `$*` in the function, it just outputs the entire keys argument on one line (treating the `c-m` as literal characters). How could I make it execute the send-keys argument as if I'd typed it from command-line?

Comment: Update: Some might be interested to know that Tmuxinator now supports a related feature, allowing key sequences inside ssh sessions among other things. See https://github.com/aziz/tmuxinator/issues/100

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use `"$@"` (the quotes are important) instead of `$*` in your shell function; it will preserve the positional parameters exactly as they are supplied in the function invocation.

```
function keys {
  tmux send-keys -t work:1 "$@"
}
```

With `"$@"`, the final command will get the four original arguments:

```
tmux send-keys -t work:1 'pwd' 'c-m' 'ls -latr' 'c-m'
```

Instead of the five from unquoted `$*`:

```
tmux send-keys -t work:1 pwd c-m ls -latr c-m
```

Or the one from `"$*"`:

```
tmux send-keys -t work:1 'pwd c-m ls -latr c-m'
```

---

When unquoted, `$*` and `$@` are effectively identical, but they are significantly different when unsed in double quotes.

- `$*` and `$@` are like `$1 $2 $3 …`

  The resulting values are subject to word splitting and filename expansion (a.k.a. globbing), so you *usually* do **not** want to use these (or any other parameter expansions) without double quotes.

  The additional word splitting is why your `"ls -ltr"` (one argument to `key`) becomes `ls -ltr` (two arguments to `tmux send-keys`).
- `"$*"` is like `"$1 $2 $3…"`

  All the positional parameter values are joined into a single “word” (string) that is protected from further word splitting and globbing.

  The character that is put between each positional parameter value is actually the first character from IFS; this is usually a plain space.
- `"$@"` is like `"$1" "$2" "$3" …`

  Each positional parameter is expanded into a separate word and they are protected from further word splitting and globbing.