# How to send a command to all panes in tmux?

Tags: tmux

I like to call `:clear-history` on panes with a huge scrollback. However, I want to script a way to send this command to all the panes in the various windows.

I know how to send a command to all the windows, courtesy of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250884/send-command-to-all-window-in-tmux), but how do I send a command to all the panes of which window as well?

`send-keys` and `synchronize-panes` from the tmux manpage come to mind, but I'm not sure how to marry them together. But maybe there is a simpler way to do this.

#### Extra Observations:

Thinking about this a little bit, `tmux list-panes -a` seems to list all the panes in the current session. Pretty useful to start off with. Where do I go from here?

Comment: For those coming to this question in the hope of finding a solution that applies to each pane, in each window, in each session: https://scripter.co/command-to-every-pane-window-session-in-tmux/

Answer (score 519, accepted):

Have you tried following in tmux window with multiple panes

```
Ctrl-B :

setw synchronize-panes on

clear history
```

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, to turn if off you'd do `Ctrl-b :setw synchronize-panes off`

Comment: and you can bind shortcuts for this on `~/.tmux.conf` by adding: `bind -n C-x setw synchronize-panes on` **and** `bind -n M-x setw synchronize-panes off`

Comment: is possible to set the same shorcut for toggling?

Comment: @ArnoldRoa yes, option will toggle if you leave `on/off`. So `bind -n C-x setw synchronize-panes`

Comment: If I add `bind -n C-x setw synchronize-panes` what short cut should I press to invoke ? Is it prefix + C&x. I tried lot of options

Comment: @BillGoldberg prefix + (CTRL  x)

Comment: Do note that while synchronize-panes does synchronise your input, it does NOT synchronise your history, so hitting arrow-up, for example, will bring up whatever was the  last thing typed in each of the panes.

Comment: @BillGoldberg The shortcut did not work for me either at first. I had to make sure that all tmux sessions were closed and tmux was not running. Otherwise the config was not reloaded

Comment: Is it possible to synchronise only some panes of a window and not all of them?

Comment: @anstue You can use "tmux source ~/.tmux.conf" (or wherever you keep your tmux.conf file) while tmux is running. This works the same way as "source ~/.bashrc", and reloads the config while the system is running. This worked for me.

Comment: What if I wanted to synchronize only a subset of the panes I have? Is it possible?

Comment: why is `clear history` needed?

Answer (score 36):

A bit late to the party but I didn't want to set and unset synchronize-panes just to send one command so I created a wrapper function around tmux and added a custom function called `send-keys-all-panes`.

```
_tmux_send_keys_all_panes_ () {
  for _pane in $(tmux list-panes -F '#P'); do
    tmux send-keys -t ${_pane} "$@"
  done
}
```

I also create a wrapper around the tmux command to simplify calling this function (for convenience). The wrapper and the above code are all [here](https://github.com/kshenoy/dotfiles/blob/7d49eac148f195c85eb3883f99ec910a0fbcf211/tmux/tmuxw.bash).

This allows me to run `tmux send-keys-all-panes <command>` or `tmux skap <command` to send `<command>` to all panes.

Note that tmux is aliased to my wrapper function tmux_pp.

Comment: this is bash, but can one do the same from the tmux command prompt, I mean by doing `prefix + :`

Comment: I don't know how or if that's possible. What's your use-case scenario that you need to send a command via `<prefix>:`?

Comment: I would recommend calling the bash snippet (`: run "yourscript.sh yourargs..."`); if your command has output your active or specified pane will display the results until you press q, but in this case it shouldn't. Of course you can alias/bind this to your liking.

As an aside, inner processes may interpret your keystrokes or their effects differently, so a whitelist or blacklist on `#{pane_current_cmd}` may be necessary. I have ctrl+k bound to send ctrl+l and clear-history; this works fine for shells, but clobbers Vim's buffer. I would need refinement before I could broadcast my ctrl+k.

Comment: This may be more of an X-Y problem; the Tmux command prompt is useful, but it sounds like you're using it because you don't have another command prompt open. You can set up a key binding - without the prefix, if you like - to toggle and focus an extra pane with your shell of choice, instead of sending `<prefix>:` before each command, losing the output after leaving the command, and all of the pitfalls that come with executing through Tmux. For example, `<prefix>:run "man cat"` does not result in man appearing in `pidof man` or even `ps auxf | grep man`, nor as 'less', my current pager for man.

Comment: The link is dead

Comment: @MateuszPiotrowski Updated the link

Comment: Dead again, it would be better to just put the content into the answer.

Comment: Fixed the link to point to the latest commit so that it's resilient to any future changes. I'm doing all sorts of crap in that file so copy-pasting all of it even if it's just send-keys related will result in a wall of text

Answer (score 26):

my tmux version is 1.9a, and this works for me, one key is enough for both on and off

```
bind-key X set-window-option synchronize-panes\; display-message "synchronize-panes is now #{?pane_synchronized,on,off}"
```

Comment: This is the most elegant solution: 1 single keystroke to turn on/off. Works perfect on `tmux 3.0a`

Comment: This message also gives some user feedback when it's changed, invaluable because it's extremely hard to remember that arcane syntax for doing so in `.tmux.conf` (`\; display-message` and `#{?` ) etc.

Answer (score 23):

**Update June 2019**

Quick illustration on how to configure your own binding for **synchronize panes**.

Added the following into my `tmux.conf` (the comments certainly apply to my overall configuration):

```
# synchronize all panes in a window
# don't use control S, too easily confused
# with navigation key sequences in tmux (show sessions)
unbind C-S
bind C-Y set-window-option synchronize-panes
```

Now, I can toggle the ability to synchronize commands across multiple panes with `<C-a><C-y>`.

(Yes, I remapped the bind key to Ctrl a).

Comment: This is a very helpful answer. Thank you.

Comment: I'm confused, what's the point of `unbind C-S`?

Comment: I guess it's good form to unbind the key you're about to bind "just in case" - and in this case I think it was simply there because previous examples were binding to ctrl+s. At any rate, it it's optional, but good form. Personally, I use ctrl+s for this key binding. It's completely up to the collective you.

Answer (score 5):

None of the above answers worked for me (tmux v2.3), but this did, from the bash command line:

```bash
for _pane in $(tmux list-panes -a -F '#{pane_id}'); do 
    tmux clear-history -t ${_pane} 
done
```

A more generalized script, for tmux commands other than 'clear-history' would just replace that element with a parameter, eg. $1. Do be careful if you intend to write a script to handle a series of tmux commands, as "-t ${_pane}" will need to be applied to each.

Note that the `-a` parameter to `tmux list-panes` is required to cover all panes in all windows in all sessions. Without that, only panes in your current tmux window will be affected. If you have more than one tmux session open and only want to apply the command to panes within the current session, replace `-a` with `-s` (It's all in the tmux man page).

I haven't the mod points to comment directly on each of the above answers, so here's why they weren't working for me:

The problem that I had with @shailesh-garg 's answer was that the sync affected only commands issued within the panes, not tmux commands issued using `Ctrl-B :` which are outside the panes.

The three problems that I had with @kshenoy 's answer were that:

1. it sends keystrokes to within a pane, not to the tmux operation
   of that pane, so for instance, if one had a bash shell running in
   the pane and one used the script to send "clear-history", those
   would be the keystrokes that would appear in the bash command-line.
   A work-around would be to send "tmux clear-history" or to pre-pend
   "tmux " to "$@", but I haven't edited the answer because of my other
   problems with the answer;
2. I couldn't figure out how to send a
   new-line character without literally breaking the line;
3. Even when I did that, sending "tmux clear-history" had no effect.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to send your command to every pane in every window in every session, add this to your `.bashrc`:

```
send_command_to_every_pane() {
    for session in `tmux list-sessions -F '#S'`; do
        for window in `tmux list-windows -t $session -F '#P' | sort`; do
            for pane in `tmux list-panes -t $session:$window -F '#P' | sort`; do
                tmux send-keys -t "$session:$window.$pane" "$*" C-m
            done
        done
    done
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
send_command_to_every_pane source ~/.bash_profile
```

Change `"$*"` to `"$@"` if you want that behavior, but in my experience this is what you want.

Comment: genius. i always wanted to reload all zsh shells automatically after config change

Answer (score 2):

```
tmux send-keys -t <session id> <command> C-m
```

Replace the "session id" and "command" accordingly.

Comment: would like to say something about this alien language

Comment: What?  
English is not hard.  
But if you have something to say, then say it.

Comment: **`:D`** dude you need to add some description to your answer as it has very minimal text and for that reason Stackoverflow detects it as a spam or low quality post just add some detail to it so that it does not appear under it.

Comment: That's funny, the accepted answer has also no description and only the code, but whatever.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine `synchronize-panes` and `send-keys` in a single shortcut to send commands to all the panes:

Predefined tmux command `clear-history`:

```
bind-key C set-option -w synchronize-panes on\; clear-history \; set-option -w synchronize-panes off
```

Prompt an arbitrary tmux command:

```
bind-key p command-prompt -p "Panes command: " "set-option -w synchronize-panes on; %% ; set-option -w -u synchronize-panes"
```

Prompt an arbitrary shell command:

```
bind-key p command-prompt -p "Panes command: " "set-option -w synchronize-panes on; send-keys %%\\n ; set-option -w -u synchronize-panes"
```

Answer (score 2):

```bash
# Send the same command to all panes/windows/sessions
bind E command-prompt -p "Command:" \
       "run \"tmux list-panes -a -F '##{session_name}:##{window_index}.##{pane_index}' \
              | xargs -I PANE tmux send-keys -t PANE '%1' Enter\""
```

From [@kaushalmodi](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/).

This appears to fully answer OPs question,

> … send this command to **all the panes in the various windows**.

as it works for all panes of *all* windows, rather than just the currently-active one, like [@arcseldon's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56420131/588437) or [@LIU YUE's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59463076/588437) does.

Answer (score 1):

This is my utility function to do it, only executing the command when there there is nothing running in the pane.

```
#!/bin/bash

_send_bash_command_to_session() {
    if [[ $# -eq 0 || "$1" = "--help" ]] ; then
        echo 'Usage: _send_bash_command_to_session $session_name what ever command you want: '
        return
    fi
    input_session="$1"
    input_command="${@:2}"
    for _pane in $(tmux list-panes -s -t ${input_session} -F '#{window_index}.#{pane_index}'); do
        # only apply the command in bash or zsh panes.
        _current_command=$(tmux display-message -p -t ${input_session}:${_pane} '#{pane_current_command}')
        if [ ${_current_command} = zsh ] || [ ${_current_command} = bash ] ; then
            tmux send-keys -t ${_pane} "${input_command}" Enter
        fi
    done
}

tmux_set_venv() {
    _current_session=$(tmux display-message -p '#{session_name}')
    _send_bash_command_to_session ${_current_session} workon $1
}
```

Example targeting a session called dev, enabling a python virtualenv in all panes that are in `bash` or `zsh`, avoiding executing the command in panes with vim or any other executable:

```
_send_bash_command_to_session dev workon myvirtualenv
```

or easier to remember: to do it in the current session:

```
tmux_set_venv myvirtualenv
```

Find my [configuration file](https://github.com/phcerdan/configuration_files/blob/master/dot_files/.tmux_utils) with this function.

Answer (score 1):

By default, [byobu](https://www.byobu.org/) uses `tmux` as backend. It's a wrapper that make things much easier:

<kbd>Shift+F9</kbd>:
[image: screenshot]

<kbd>Ctrl+F9</kbd>:
[image: screenshot]

<kbd>Shift+F1</kbd>

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly only semi-related, I found I could make the status background red when I toggle synchronize-panes so it's obvious when I switch back to a window  with an unknown synchronize-panes state:

```
bind-key C-x setw synchronize-panes on \;  set-window-option status-bg red \; display-message "pane sync on"
bind-key M-x setw synchronize-panes off \;  set-window-option status-bg default \; display-message "pane sync off"
```