# How to bind a key to send shell commands (e.g. "source ~/.bashrc") to all tmux panes in all windows in a tmux session?

Tags: shell, zsh, tmux

Scenario: I edit `~/.zshrc`, and I want to source it in all of my tmux panes, in all windows, in a given session.  I want to do this with a keybinding, from any pane.

I tried looking at [How to send a command to all panes in tmux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325449/how-to-send-a-command-to-all-panes-in-tmux), which used `setw synchronize-panes on` and then ran a tmux ex mode command; but I'd like to run `source $HOME/.zshrc`, (a shell command), and I'm a little confused as to how to do that.

I'd like it to be a keybinding that I can put into `.tmux.conf`, so that I only have to press *prefix + <key_combo>* to perform this, and then everything returns to the way it was before I ran this (e.g. I don't have to worry about unsetting any tmux options that the command set)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work for you:

```
# send "source ~/.bashrc<Enter>" to all panes in *current* session
bind  B  run 'panes=`tmux list-panes -s -F "##{pane_id}"`; \
              for pane in $panes; do \
                tmux send -t $pane "source ~/.bashrc" Enter; \
              done'

# send "source ~/.zshrc<Enter>" to all panes in *current* session
bind  Z  run 'panes=`tmux list-panes -s -F "##{pane_id}"`; \
              for pane in $panes; do \
                tmux send -t $pane "source ~/.zshrc" Enter; \
              done'
```

Comment: thanks for the reply; this worked great, except in panes where another process, e.g. `vim`, is running (for vim panes it ran the "s" command (substitute 1 character), and then entered `ource ~/.zshrc`, and stayed in insert mode, as expected).

vim is usually the only longstanding process I have running in panes in a session; is there a way to check that the foreground process in a pane is zsh, or not vim (for a narrower case), and only run this command in those panes?

Comment: that's not easy to be answered in the comment. please ask a new question.