# How to close all windows to the right in tmux

Tags: tmux, tmuxinator

Is there a way to issue a command to close all tmux windows unless something is open in that window? For example, an open file, a running process, etc.?

I am hoping for something that functions as a web browser where you can right click and select `close all other tabs to the right.` I'd like to issue this in tmux, and similar to the web browser example, have "busy" windows or panes prompt me to close them or silently fail to close.

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250884/send-command-to-all-window-in-tmux), but I don't necessarily want to issue the command to all windows.

Comment: There is a way, but it's not built in. You will have to script it. You can get the number of current panes with `#{window_panes}` and loop over them and make sure the pane number under test is greater than the current pane (i.e., to the right of the current pane). Then just send a `kill pane` for that pane.

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just built a script to do so, here it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os
import re

result = subprocess.run(['tmux', 'list-windows'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

result = result.stdout.decode('utf-8')

lines = result.splitlines()
should_close_next = False
for line in lines:

    if should_close_next:
        window = line.split(':')[0]
        os.system(f'tmux kill-window -t {window}')
        continue

    match = re.search("active", line)
    if match:
        should_close_next = True
```

And to integrate it with your tmux add to your tmux.conf

```
bind-key "k" run-shell "kill_panes_to_right.py\n"
```

Best

Answer (score 2):

Here's a shell alternative:

```sh
for win_id in $(tmux list-windows -F '#{window_active} #{window_id}' | awk '/^1/ { active=1; next } active { print $2 }'); do tmux kill-window -t "$win_id"; done
```

And here's the same (readable version):

```sh
for win_id in $(tmux list-windows -F '#{window_active} #{window_id}' | \
                awk '/^1/ { active=1; next } active { print $2 }')
do 
  tmux kill-window -t "$win_id"
done
```

Edit: I made a plugin with this!
https://github.com/pschmitt/tmux-forsaken